# Como saca el valor de una tabla html seleccionando la fila

Tags: html, jquery, sql

Tengo este código y la tabla se llena con los datos de una consulta de Query pero no me reconoce las filas de la consulta, solo toma en cuenta el titulo y no reconoce las demas.

Asi se llena la tabla, esto es el codigo del Jquery se llama con una funcion y llena los datos con el valor de "contenedor" que llena el tbody.

```
function DatosUsuarios()
{
  var sas="";
   $.ajax({

       headers:{'Authorization':'bearer '+localStorage.authentication},
       type: "GET",
       url: "http://localhost:8008/api/v1/product",
       contentType: 'application/json',
       success: function (response) {
           let vacio = `<tr><td colspan="4">SIN REGISTROS</td></tr>`;
           if(response.length > 0)
           {
               let filas = ``;
               $.each(response,function(i, item){
                   filas += `<tr><td>${item.requisition_id}</td><td>${item.fecha}</td><td>${item.nombre}</td><td>${item.address}</td></tr>`;
                   console.log(item);
                   sas = item.requisition_id+"_";
               });
               $('#contenedor').html(filas)
           }
           else{
               $('#contenedor').html(vacio)
           }
       },
       error: function(){
           Refresh();
           DatosUsuarios();
       }
   });
}
```

Este es el codigo de html que llena la tabla

```
<div class="tab content1">
  <div class="container">
  <table class="table table-striped table-hovered" id="table">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Numero de pedido</th>
      <th>Fecha de pedido</th>
      <th>Cliente</th>
      <th>Direccion</th>
      <th></th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody id="contenedor">

      </tbody>
  </table>
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-10 col-md-offset-2">
        <button class="btn btn-outline-dark" id="btnAcceder">Actualizar datos</button>
      </div>
  </div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

Y esta es la funcion que deberia devolverme el valor de la fila

```
   $("#table tr").click(function(){
   $(this).addClass('selected').siblings().removeClass('selected');
   var value=$(this).find('td:first').html();
   alert(value);
    });
```

Comment: que te muestra la salida de _console.log(item);_?

Comment: Me muestra esto:  Object { requisition_id: 8, fecha: "2020-05-10", nombre: "Jorge Perez", address: "Zona Bello Horizonte Calle 38 Nro. 24" }   si se llena la tabla pero no al hace clic en ella no saca ningun valor como deberia.

Comment: creo que entendí mal tu pregunta, el problema no es para llenar la tabla, ¿si no que para obtener el valor de la fila ?

Comment: Si, no obtiene ningun valor cuando le doy click a la tabla, si le doy click al titulo si obtiene el valor pero los datos que han sido llenados por el query no los toma en cuenta.

Comment: y si en el alert pones $(this).val() o $(this).html(), es que creo que en ese this ya tienes la información de tu fila.

Comment: sigue sin dar, si selecciono la fila de títulos si me devuelve los valores pero de lo demás nada.

Comment: Acabo de hacer un ejemplo y me funciono con esta linea **var value=$(this).html();**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Prueba con esto. espero sea lo que necesitas.

```
$("#tabla").on("click", "tbody tr", function (event) {
      var Id= this.cells[0].innerHTML; //valor de primera columna
      var Nombre= this.cells[1].innerHTML; //valor de segunda columna

  });
```

yo lo hago de esta manera.
suerte.

Comment: Si, esto me funciono mil gracias.